# Text to HTML converter for making forum

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-apps

I am looking for a **javascript (jquery) or Djangon app** as a Text to HTML converter to use in my site'**forum**.

something like [**markdown**](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most popular code for forum is somehow like:

- BBCode
- Wiki Format
- Markdown

or tookit like http://ckeditor.com/